# Is there a way to repeat a binding?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm maintaining some code where there is, unfortunately, a wide use of references to keep track of states within the program. There's a particularly egregious use of them in one module which updates numerous values via Euler's method:

```
eulerUpdate states timestep = do
  _val1  <- readReference (val1 states)
  _dval1 <- readReference (dval1 states) 
  _val2  <- readReference (val2 states)
  _dval2 <- readReference (dval2 states)
    -- ...
  _valn  <- readReference (valn states)
  _dvaln <- readReference (dvaln states)
  let euler val deriv = val + deriv * timestep
  writeReference (val1 states) euler _val1 _dval1
    -- ...
  writeReference (valn states) euler _valn _dvaln
```

I'm relatively new to Haskell, but my understanding is that this a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad thing. Instead of refactoring everything else around it, I was hoping there might be some way to at least compact it into fewer LOC for readability. Is there anything that could be done here to "map" the `readReference (x states)` into a bunch of identifiers? I've looked more into Kliesli arrows but I don't see much that will help me here.

Comment: those probably have all different types right? If not you should be able to translate this into a list-representation using `mapM` or `forM` - but it will not get much nicer I guess - but if you look closely it seems that you only use 2 values together so instead of a really long list why don't you make use of this?

Comment: I don't think there's any need for some fancy refactoring technique, a simple function will probably do the trick. e.g. something like `f :: (States -> Reference a) -> (States -> Reference b) -> (a -> b -> IO a) -> IO a = \val dval f -> join (f <$> readReference (val states) <*> readReference (dval states)) >>= writeReference (val states)` - obviously without knowing exact types (at least) I couldn't say exactly how it would look. If all the references have the same type, use some sort of `map`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: is it possible to rearrange read and write operations? If so, you can get away with something as simple as

```
let updateOne val dval = do
    _val = readReference (val states)
    _dval = readReference (dval states)
    writeReference (val states) (euler _val _dval)
```

and then just use it like

```
eulerUpdate states timestep = do
    updateOne val1 dval1
    updateOne val2 dval2
    ...
```

If not, and writing upsets the reading, well, you might want to get creative and keep read and write operations separate, but in the same structure:

```
data ReadWriteReference where
    ReadWriteReference :: (States -> IO a) -> (States -> a -> IO ()) -> ReadWriteReference
performReadWrite :: States -> ReadWriteReference -> IO ()
performReadWrite states (ReadWriteReference read write) = do
    a <- read states
    write states a
makeRW :: (States -> Reference) -> (States -> Reference) -> ReadWriteReference
makeRW val dval = ReadWriteReference read write where
    read states = do
        _val <- readReference (val states)
        _dval <- readReference (dval states)
        writeReference (val states) (euler _val _dval)
(<+>) :: ReadWriteReference -> ReadWriteReference -> ReadWriteReference
ReadWriteReference read1 write1 <+> ReadWriteReference read2 write2 = ReadWriteReference read write where
    read states = do
        a <- read1 states
        b <- read2 states
        return (a, b)
    write states (a, b) = do
        write1 states a
        write2 states b
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
performReadWrite states $ makeRW val1 dval1 <+> makeRW val2 dval2 <+> ... <+> makeRW valn dvaln
```

You can even make ReadWriteReference an instance of Monoid and use standard combinators.